# Why is the "last seen 96 years ago" feature gone?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

User homepages used to display the information "last seen ... (min/days/...) ago". It appears this feature is gone now.

I found it useful, and while it does divulge some otherwise unavailable information, this didn't seem of a particularly sensitive type.

My typical use of the feature would involve comments that I want to delete, but only after a certain user has read them (such as "sorry, my previous comment was complete nonsense, you are right").

For example: [image]

Comment: I still see that information, just like before -- but maybe this is mod-specific(?) -- Could you perhaps provide a screenshot? In any case, I think if that information is really not generally available any more, this would be a loss.

Comment: It's also gone on the mod side for me.

Comment: This is related to recent (controversial) changes in the whole SE network, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Well -- that information is available under the 'Profile' tab (and not under the 'Activity' tab which is shown in the screenshot) -- but wasn't this always so?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Not for me, see the updated screenshot please.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I still see that information. -- E.g. you are now shown on the main site as "Last seen 25 mins ago" / "2021-08-11 19:16:37Z" (with mouse over). -- Maybe the change is rolled out over some time, and different users see it not simultaneously(?)

Comment: @StefanKohl Maybe. I don't see exactly what you see but I don't know why.

Comment: @StefanKohl As a moderator, you still have access to the "Last seen" value for all users. However, it's not available to anybody else. The [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/562482)  Francesco linked to states in $2.$ that "... some stats behind are only viewable by you or a moderator." My [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368289/562482) to that question asks why "Last seen" was removed, plus what, if anything, are the future plans for it. Also, the specific use of that feature I stated in my answer is the same as what Christian mentions in the question here.

Comment: I see the "last seen" information on the Physics Stack Exchange site where I'm a mod, but not on other sites.

Comment: A related post on [math.meta.se]: [Why has the number of profile views been removed from MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33982)

Comment: And it was spawned by **[this terrible UI change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285), which as of now has score −281**.

Comment: I think that this information is still being collected and displayed on "Network Profile" pages.  (This information is visible when I visit a Network Profile page logged out and in incognito mode, so cannot depend on any special privileges.)  In particular, the "last-seen" information there is (at least) day-granular, not the week-granular that was supposedly restored yesterday as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285/some-changes-to-the-profile-while-we-make-it-responsive/368328#comment1241156_368328.  I am not sure what to make of this.

Comment: @dvitek: Yes, it appears some variant of it is back, but for me it's week-wise, so if you visited 3 min ago, it will say "last seen this week".